# How to unmarshal interface{} into a int64

Tags: go, unmarshalling

I have a structure. The `id` can come as a string or as a number. To process it, I specified its type as `interface`.

```
type Request struct {
    Id   interface{} `json:"id"`
    Code string      `json:"code"`
}
```

As far as I understand, if a number comes in, it is converted to `float64`, but this leads to a loss of accuracy. I need it to be converted to `int64`, but I don't understand how to do it without losing accuracy

```
func main() {
    jsonData := []byte(`{"id": 123456789123456789, "code":"123"}`)

    var request Request
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &request)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error JSON:", err)
        return
    }

    if value, ok := request.Id.(int64); ok {
        fmt.Println("Result:", value)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Error. Type: %T", value)
    }
    //Output: Error. Type: int64

    res := int64(request.Id.(float64))
    fmt.Println(res)
   //Output:123456789123456784. Expected: 123456789123456789
}
```

Comment: Use `int64` or  `json.Number` instead of `interface{}` for the `Id` field.

Comment: Alternatively, implement `json.Unmarshaler` for the `Request` type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json.NewDecoder` with **UseNumber** function. After that according to data type should parse your data:

- int64 sample ([Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/QIxJ5R-1QCC))

```golang
func main() {
    jsonData := []byte(`{"id": 123456789123456789, "code":"123"}`)

    d := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(jsonData))
    d.UseNumber()

    var request Request
    err := d.Decode(&request)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error JSON:", err)
        return
    }

    var id int64
    switch v := request.Id.(type) {
    case string:
        id, err = strconv.ParseInt(v, 10, 64)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    case json.Number:
        id, err = v.Int64()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    default:
        log.Fatalf("I don't know about type %T!\n", v)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Type: %T\nValue: %v\n", id, id)
}
```

- string sample ([Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/1mqli2DP0_i))

```golang
func main() {
    jsonData := []byte(`{"id": "123456789123456789", "code":"123"}`)

    d := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(jsonData))
    d.UseNumber()

    var request Request
    err := d.Decode(&request)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error JSON:", err)
        return
    }

    var id int64
    switch v := request.Id.(type) {
    case string:
        id, err = strconv.ParseInt(v, 10, 64)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    case json.Number:
        id, err = v.Int64()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    default:
        log.Fatalf("I don't know about type %T!\n", v)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Type: %T\nValue: %v\n", id, id)
}
```